# Is it possible to build a react app from within codesandbox itself?

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app, codesandbox

Is it possible to create a build of a react app created with the codesandbox template by running `npm run build` on codesandbox itself?

In short is it possible to run npm scripts on codesandbox

If yes, how?

Comment: https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1608

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to use a container sandbox like [Node](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-http-server-node) that exposes a terminal. There's more info on the difference between container and client sandboxes in our docs: https://codesandbox.io/docs/environment